# Error trying to create a dialog popup using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am a jQuery newbie and I am trying to open a popup dialog box to the user in case of

```
error : function(data)
```

What I have in the jQuery code so far is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{
   var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
           .html('This dialog will show every time!')
           .dialog({
               autoOpen: false,
               title: 'Basic Dialog'
           });

    $('.vote_up').click(function() 
    {        
        alert ( "test: " + $(this).attr("data-problem_id") );
        problem_id = $(this).attr("data-problem_id");

        var dataString = 'problem_id='+ problem_id + '&vote=+';

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/problems/vote.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(data)
                {           
                    // ? :)
                    alert (data);   
                },
                error : function(data) 
                {
                    //alert("ajax error, json: " + data.responseText);
                    errorMessage = data.responseText;

                    if ( errorMessage == "not_logged_in" )
                    {
                        alert ("errr");

                        // Try to create the popup that asks user to log in.
                        //$(this).dialog();

                        $dialog.dialog('open');
                        // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert ("not");
                    }

                    //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                    //for (var i = 0, l = json.length; i < l; ++i) 
                    //{
                    //  alert (json[i]);
                    //}
                }
            });


        //Return false to prevent page navigation
        return false;
    });

    $('.vote_down').click(function() 
    {
        alert("down");

        problem_id = $(this).attr("data-problem_id");

        var dataString = 'problem_id='+ problem_id + '&vote=-';        

        //Return false to prevent page navigation
        return false;
    });    
});
</script>
```

I get a JavaScript error that Object has no method dialog.  That seems Greek to me :)

The error is happening here if you press the "vote up" link: http://www.problemio.com

How can I fix this?  Will it be possible for me to make that dialog appear? It will be to ask people to log into the site or sign up.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the [jQuery UI JavaScript and CSS files](http://jqueryui.com/download) on your page. You also need to attach the dialog elements to the page's DOM:

```
var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
       .html('This dialog will show every time!')
       .appendTo('body')
       .dialog({
           autoOpen: false,
           title: 'Basic Dialog'
       });
```

---

Side note: I strongly encourage you to update to a newer version of jQuery. Your site is using 1.3 (released in January of 2009); [the latest version](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery) is 1.6.4 (September 2011).

Comment: I'll update the jQuery version.  Is it just as simple as swapping out the link in the header to reference to the new one?

Comment: Yes and no. The upgrade may break existing functionality in your current code.

Comment: by the way, what is the difference in doing the .appendTo('body') like you suggest and the other suggestion on the page for making a new div and appending to that div?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure var `$dialog = $('<div></div>')`  is strickly legit!

I think you need to do this;

var `$dialog = $('.MyDiv')`

and then

```
<div class="MyDiv"></div>
```

Comment: I see - where should I put that div on the page? On the very bottom somewhere below the footer?  Does it matter where it will be?  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah just stick it on the page somewhere as the jQuery ui will place it later on